# How to run the docker images that i pulled the "sudo docker pull ppc64le/alpine:edge" , but i am getting error while running this image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

These are the methods tried to run the image , can anyone please help in running this edge pulled image.

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t ppc64le/alpine:edge /bin/sh -c "echo hello"
exec format error
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container f6d4a9675de787258cdb0dd7f25abc2f51e956790a6f9b408da56af2fa309320: [9] System error: exec format error.
```

Where the normal alpine will work properly

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t alpine /bin/sh -c "echo hello"
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/alpine ... 
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/alpine

627beaf3eaaf: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:58e1a1bb75db1b5a24a462dd5e2915277ea06438c3f105138f97eb53149673c4
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/alpine:latest
hello
```

These are the images list , but i need to run the **docker.io/ppc64le/alpine** image .

```
]$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/ppc64le/ubuntu            16.04               8a9bece55fb5        5 days ago          157.1 MB
docker.io/ppc64le/debian            latest              ed3456c89713        6 days ago          127.9 MB
docker.io/ubuntu                    latest              f7b3f317ec73        9 days ago          117.3 MB
docker.io/fedora                    latest              15895ef0b3b2        12 days ago         230.9 MB
**docker.io/ppc64le/alpine            edge                736257f91720        3 weeks ago         4.798 MB**
docker.io/ppc64le/fedora            latest              b288a3394151        3 months ago        349.4 MB
```

Comment: The command you provided, `docker run -i -t ppc64le/alpine:edge /bin/sh -c "echo hello"`, works perfect. May be something mess in your environment. Remove the image and retry.

Comment: The command which i was running on the RHEL machine with X86 arch . where i am getting this error , then i tried to run on the RHEL ppc64le arch machine , it works perfect .

Comment: Ok, glad you could nailed it.